# How to fetch 20 message Data from sqlite3 database in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, fetch, pull-to-refresh

following is my code:

```
- (void)crunchNumbers
{
     manage=[[DBManager alloc]init];
     arrfrmdb2=[NSMutableArray new];
     [manage fetchConversationDatagroup:_user];
     arrfrmdb2 =[manage arrayConvData];

     [newMessageArray removeAllObjects];
     for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {                   
        [newMessageArray addObject:[arrfrmdb2 objectAtIndex:i]];    
     }
     [_bubbleTable reloadData];

     [self performSelector:@selector(containtreload) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
}
```

Hello I am working on chat app. In chat screen I want used pull to refresh in that I want fetch 20 message from database for 1 time refresh.
please give me exact solution.

Comment: have you tried something

Comment: NSString *sqlStatement_userInfo =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from CONVERSATION WHERE oiwii_id ='%@'LIMIT 20",selectedOiwii_ID];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int startcounter=0;
```

Follow these process every time

```
NSString *sqlStatement_userInfo =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from CONVERSATION WHERE oiwii_id ='%@' LIMIT '%d',20 order by id asc",selectedOiwii_ID,startcounter]; –
```

and update

```
startcounter=startcounter+20;
```